# semodule -i takes 100% cpu and does not end

Tags: installation, selinux

I am setting up selinux and ran

```
grep ${1} /var/log/audit/audit.log | audit2allow -r -M local_${1}
```

within an compilation script (oneliner).

I'd like to run it like "compile_selinux collectd_t" so it grabs me all relevant issues. Now I can review the .te file with what audit2allow -a returns me.

Next thing is installing the module by running

```
semodule -i local_collectd_t.pp
```

But this command does not return and uses up 100% cpu. I have been waiting for 3.5 hours now. I don't know whats wrong and hope you could help me.

Example for collectd_t:

```
module local_collectd_t 1.0;

require {
        type var_log_t;
        type collectd_t;
        type openvpn_var_log_t;
        class file { read open };
}

#============= collectd_t ==============
allow collectd_t openvpn_var_log_t:file { read open };
allow collectd_t var_log_t:file open;
```

Thanks for help

Silberling

Comment: Is it still running?

Comment: Cancelled it :-S

Comment: After half a day it says:
libsepol.check_assertion_helper: neverallow violated by allow restorecond_t semanage_store_t:file { relabelto };
libsemanage.semanage_expand_sandbox: Expand module failed
semodule:  Failed!

Comment: You've got some other issue with your system. That should have taken only a minute or two, even on a very old and slow system.